# Any way to prevent Mac firewall from asking to allow connections all the time?

Tags: mac-os-x

Whenever I start Mathematica 8 on my Mac the built-in Mac OS firewall asks if I want to allow JLink to accept incoming connections. Then, during running, I'll get the same question about Mathematica.app. Sometimes the requests occur several times during the day, though not always. It's a minor irritation but it'd be nice to know if there is a way to avoid it while keeping the firewall switched on.

I already have the Mac firewall configured to allow connections permanently for Mathematica.app and JLink.

Thanks

Comment: What does this terminal command say for you?  

codesign -vvv /Applications/Mathematica.app  

It should say this:  

/Applications/Mathematica.app: valid on disk  
/Applications/Mathematica.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement

Comment: It does indeed say that, @cormullion

Comment: Oh well. I read somewhere that it would say something else if it was a code signing issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've had this issue for a long time and the only change that "fixed" it is to block all incoming connections. Go to `System Preferences > Personal > Security & Privacy > Firewall Options` and select `Block all incoming connections` as shown (you will have to unlock and enter your administrator password):

[image]

#### A less drastic, but possibly riskier option

The reason this occurs has to do with the signature of the app. Sometimes, re-installing the app will fix the problem. If not, an option would be to sign the app yourself. You can read [this blog post](http://silvanolte.com/blog/2011/01/18/do-you-want-the-application-to-accept-incoming-network-connections/) for directions on how to sign the app yourself. However, do note that if *you* sign the app, the OS treats it as a very secure app and might be oblivious to other hitherto unknown (possibly malicious) behaviour from the app.

For the aforementioned reasons, I did not choose to go this route. Blocking all incoming connections might seem drastic, but I have not had any issues so far and I can `ssh` to my computer perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure that will work for me as I have quite a few things in my exceptions list. Will leave this open for a bit in case anyone else has a workaround a bit less drastic!

Comment: @TimKemp See my edit... there's a way to override it by signing the app yourself. I didn't choose this route, but doesn't mean that you shouldn't.

Comment: I'll investigate your blog link. Thanks for this. It smells like an Apple problem more than a Wolfram one; I have seen the behaviour in some other programs too.